# Offline refresh token using Google APIs

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, oauth2client

I'm trying to use Google Analytics API and have access while the user is offline. I use the oauth2decorator_from_clientsecrets to get the credentials initially(which should request offline access by default). I am able to access the API for 1 hour before the token expires as expected. After this, I end up getting an error of:

"AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant"

I am using the following code to access the API with stored credentials:

```
credentials = StorageByKeyName(CredentialsModel, user_id, 'credentials').get()
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
analytics = build("analytics", "v3", http=http)
query = analytics.management().webproperties().list(accountId="123456").execute()
```

I suspect this has something to do with not getting initial offline access permission properly. When the user is initially directed to the authorization url, I cannot see the expected confirmation of

> "Perform these operations when I'm not using the application"

Instead, what I see is:

[image: confirmation url]

Also, I am using the "Client ID for web applications" for my application.

Cheers!

Comment: Do you have a `refresh_token` property in the `CredentialsModel` stored in the datastore after granting the permission?

Comment: After constructing the OAuth2Decorator can you print: `decorator.flow.params['access_type']`?

Comment: Sorry, It's showing 'offline' which is what I'm after. Not sure how else to approach the problem.

Comment: Yes, I have a refresh_token property

Comment: Is your application always calling GA API with the same credentials/Users? If yes you might consider add the application service account to your API Project and use `AppAssertionCredentials`.

Comment: Can you update your post with more logs, see: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/logging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not happy about spending all day on this issue, but here's the solution I had.

I [revoked](https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens) the application I had made from the user, then I deleted the credentials stored from my database.

I'm sure I'd already done that as a first step, but apparently not.

There's 10 hours of my life I won't get back. Hope this is useful to someone.

Comment: had the same problem, you were right, visiting the https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens page and revoking rights was the only way to get the refresh token